# How to show Emoji from database in Grails

Tags: mysql, grails, emoji

I want to save nickname from wechat to Mysql and show it exactly in HTML.The problem is the nickname may contain emoji.
Now I can save emoji to Mysql([Switching from MySQL’s utf8 to utf8mb4](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4)).But how to show it? Is there any solution?(I use Grails and Mysql.)

Comment: The emoji you talk about, is it Unicode emoji (e.g. as \u1F603) or some bespoken image files (i.e. gif)?

Comment: I save it in Mysql as utf8mb4 character.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to set your JDBC connection string, URL, (in `Datasource.groovy`) to include

```
jdbc:mysql://server_ip:server_port/db_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

Comment: This is my dataSource url.But it isn't my point.I want to know how to show emoji which is from Mysql in HTML.

Comment: Did you find any solution by now? I've got the same problem.

Comment: This throw a `SQLNestedException (Unsupported character encoding 'utf-8mb4'.)`